# How to position bubble animation properly?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to finish this AI chat app, and I am having an issue with my bubble animation being in the center of the chat window. Basically when the response is being generated, there is an animation playing, similarly as in iMessage and it works fine besides being positioned in the middle of the window. My suspicion is it has to do something with the  `GeometryReader` on line 90.

[image: Here is what it looks like]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isTyping = false // to show animation
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Chat messages
            Text("Chat messages")
            
            // Bubble animation
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                if isTyping {
                    AnimatedDotsView()
                        .position(x: geometry.size.width / 2, y: geometry.size.height / 2)
                }
            }
            
            // User input
            TextField("Send a message", text: .constant(""))
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding()
            
            // Button
            Button(action: {
                isTyping.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Toggle Animation")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct AnimatedDotsView: View {
    @State private var dot1Animating = false
    @State private var dot2Animating = false
    @State private var dot3Animating = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 3) {
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(dot1Animating ? .gray : .green)
                .frame(width: 5, height: 5)
                .scaleEffect(dot1Animating ? 1 : 0.2)
                .onAppear {
                    withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.8).repeatForever(autoreverses: true).delay(0.1)) {
                        dot1Animating = true
                    }
                }
            
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(dot2Animating ? .gray : .green)
                .frame(width: 5, height: 5)
                .scaleEffect(dot2Animating ? 1 : 0.2)
                .onAppear {
                    withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.8).repeatForever(autoreverses: true).delay(0.2)) {
                        dot2Animating = true
                    }
                }
            
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(dot3Animating ? .gray : .green)
                .frame(width: 5, height: 5)
                .scaleEffect(dot3Animating ? 1 : 0.2)
                .onAppear {
                    withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.8).repeatForever(autoreverses: true).delay(0.3)) {
                        dot3Animating = true
                    }
                }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 6)
        .padding(.vertical, 8)
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
        )
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I tried using `GeometryReader` and some padding, but it is not the right way doing it.

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
                if isTyping {
                    AnimatedDotsView()
                        .position(x: geometry.size.width / 2, y: geometry.size.height / 2)
                }
            }
```

Ultimately I would like the animation to be on the left side where the AI response is generated.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Right now you have too much code which has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `GeometryReader`. Just do what you did for the AI's responses, namely, with an `HStack` containing a `Spacer` at the end.

```
if isTyping {
    HStack {
        AnimatedDotsView()
        Spacer()
    }
    .padding(.horizontal, 10)
}
```

You can put this as the last item in the `VStack` containing all the messages, or put it just before the "Send a message" text field.

e.g.

```
ScrollView {
    VStack(spacing: 10) {
        ForEach(messages) { message in
            HStack {
                if message.isUser {
                    Spacer()
                }
                Text(message.text)
                    .padding(7)
                    .background(
                        message.isUser ?
                        Color.blue :
                        Color(red: 0.3, green: 0.3, blue: 0.3)
                    )
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .frame(maxWidth: 250, alignment: message.isUser ? .trailing : .leading)
                if !message.isUser {
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
        }
        if isTyping {
            HStack {
                AnimatedDotsView()
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
        }
    }
    .padding(.top, 50)
}
```